# Regex for a dynamic string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that can come in different forms - one example below

```
%VAR('SERVER','DEFAULT') %VAR('LOC','NYC')Run_ServerRestart.ps1
```

I want to separate them as individual items and am not able to separate out the command in the end as a match. My regex returns 2 matches for the above example while I am looking to get 3 matches. Any ideas on what I maybe doing wrong and how to separate out them as below and if there is a more efficient way to achieve this ? We need to accommodate for spaces anywhere in between as well.

- %VAR('SERVER','DEFAULT')
- %VAR('LOC','NYC')
- Run_ServerRestart.ps1

Here is my regex so far:

```
/%VAR\(\s*'([^']+)'\s*\)*\,*\s*'([^']+)'\s*\)|/*\\*[\w-]+\s*\.?\S*/g
```

However, this above regex is not matching some of my examples below.

- `c:\abc\def.txt` - should show 1 match
- `%VAR('SERVER','USA')\C:\batch.bat` - should show 2 matches -    `%VAR('SERVER', 'USA')` and `\c:\batch.bat`
- `%VAR('SERVER','NYC')` -    should show 1 match
- `%VAR('SERVER','NYC')    %VAR('APP','NNJ')Run_Command.ps1` -  should show 3 matches
- `%VAR('SERVER','NYC')  %VAR('APP','NNJ')` and `Run_Command.ps1`
- `%VAR('SERVER','NYC') -File` - should show 2 matches - `%VAR('SERVER','NYC')` and `-File`
- `/usr/bin/cat` - should show 1 match
- `%VAR('SERVER','NYC')BATCH1.bat` - should show 2 matches -    `%VAR('SERVER','NYC')` and `BATCH1.bat`
- `ftp -s:D:\\apps\\scripts\\Intel\\daily_job.ftp` - should show 1 match
- `%VAR('SERVER')` - should show 1 match

Comment: Is it always in the form where it first sets variables then is followed by a command? `%VAR %VAR ... command` Are spaces between the %VARs required or optional? `%VAR(a,b)%VAR(x,y)`

Comment: There may be a command or sometimes no command at all, just the variables like %VAR('SERVER', 'DEFAULT')

Comment: So I would define that as one or more vars, optionally followed by a command. Abstractly, that pattern is `(var)+(command)?` Then `var` and `command` need to be broken down to match what a _var_ looks like, and what a _command_ looks like. A var is literal `%VAR(` quoted_string `comma` quoted_string `)` etc. This is how I break down what needs to be in a regex.

Comment: @S.Kablar, 1 match means that the entire string comes out as a group. c:\abc\def.txt - should show 1 match - when I use Patterns in java, it should come out as the entire string here without leaving out anything  - c:\abc\def.txt

Comment: @S.Kablar, thank you. wondering why it throws off 'ftp' though.

Comment: even in this command - it leaves '\' in the command before C:\- VAR('SERVER','USA')\C:\batch.bat

Comment: Try this one https://regex101.com/r/VhUa1U/7 hope it works.

Comment: @S.Kablar, You are amazing buddy ! cant thank you enough ! this problem ate away half my day today !

Comment: I updated my regex to more cleaner version. Please change yours and delete all messages below my answer.

Comment: @S.Kablar, Thank you for the update. I didnt quite understand which messages you want me to delete - the comments in your answer thread below or the comments on this thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**: `%VAR\([^\)]+\)|[\S]+(?:\s[\S]+)?`

**Details**:

- `[^]` Match a single character not present in the list
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `*` Matches between zero and unlimited times
- `|` or
- `(?:)` Non capturing group
- `?` Matches between zero and one times
- `\S` matches any non-whitespace character (equal to `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
- `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VhUa1U/8)

Comment: Pretty close. How do I make the last command include '_', '-' and any extension after a period (if there is one at all) ? Not all commands can be ps1

Comment: %VAR('LOC','NYC')%VAR('LOC','NYC')shell_cmd.sh 

or

%VAR('LOC','NYC')%VAR('LOC','NYC') mycommand

Comment: Need to accommodate for any spaces anywhere inbetween too

Comment: Think I got it using this : /%VAR\('([^']+)','([^']+)'\)|\S+\.?[0-9a-zA-Z]*/g

Comment: @Prashanth Updated! You "accommodate" for any spaces anywhere inbetween...

Comment: This is also possible - spaces before a quote or after and before a comma.    %VAR( 'LOC' , 'NYC') %VAR('LOC','NYC') mycommand

Comment: @Prashanth Updated!

Comment: sorry to bother you with another q on this same topic - appreciate if you can pls help !

Comment: @Prashanth Yes?

Comment: /%VAR\(\s*'([^']+)'\s*\)*|\,\s*'([^']+)'\s*\)|/*\\*[\w-]+\s*\.?\S*/g doesnt seem to match %VAR('SERVER') fully - it leaves out the % in the beginning. Would you know what I am doing wrong ? It does match %VAR('SERVER', 'NYC') though as 1 match.

Comment: @Prashanth Try `\%` instead of `%`.

Comment: With regex - /%VAR\(\s*'([^']+)'\s*\)*|,\s*'([^']+)'\s*\)|/*\\*[\w-]+\s*\.?\S*/g it matches %VAR('SERVER') but not %VAR('SERVER', 'NYC'). Not sure how to get both of them working as one match

Comment: @Prashanth What problems you have with my regex?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163894/discussion-between-prashanth-and-s-kablar).

Comment: As I said in my most recent comment, the regex matches one of the two input strings I have as 1 match while it says 2 matches for the other string. I am trying to get 1 match for both input strings.

Comment: @Prashanth I really don't understand what you want. Please update your question above with examples and end results.

Comment: added a few more examples to the question. 3rd example is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they always look exactly like this you can just abuse the `)` as a separator

```
(.*\))\s(.*\))(.*)
```

Example with explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/CLBFKa/1

Comment: It depends on the number of variables

Comment: @Prashanth Is there always a space between the variables?